# Server Side b-table vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to show the data from the server and that the table is automatically updated every time I find a new record in the database, I am using b-table from bootstrap vue, I was reading the documentation but it does not show how to configure the server side correctly , I would like to do something similar as in datatable but using bootstrap's b-table.

Try to update the table every so often with a setInteval, but I don't know if it is very productive to do this or is there any way to improve the update:

**time interval:**

```
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.getInventories()
    }, 5000)
  },
```

**My Table:**

```
  <b-table
    v-if="!loading"
    ref="refInventoryListTable"
    class="position-relative animated fadeIn"
    :items="items"
    :fields="columns"
    responsive
    primary-key="id"
    :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
    show-empty
    :empty-text="empty"
    :sort-desc.sync="isSortDirDesc"
    :filter="filter"
    :empty-filtered-text="empty"
    :current-page="currentPage"
    :per-page="0"
  >

    <!-- Column: Status -->
    <template #cell(status)="data">
      <b-form-checkbox
        :checked="[data.item.status == 1 ? 'true' : 'false']"
        :class="[data.item.status == 1 ? 'custom-control-success' : 'custom-control-secondary']"
        name="check-button"
        switch
        @change="changeStatus(data.item.id)"
      />
    </template>

    <!-- Column: Actions -->
    <template #cell(actions)="data">
      <b-dropdown
        variant="link"
        no-caret
        :right="$store.state.appConfig.isRTL"
      >

        <template #button-content>
          <feather-icon
            icon="MoreVerticalIcon"
            size="16"
            class="align-middle text-body"
          />
        </template>
        <!-- eslint-disable-next-line -->
        <b-dropdown-item 
          v-b-modal.editInventory
          @click="editInventory(data.item)"
        >
          <feather-icon icon="EditIcon" />
          <span class="align-middle ml-50">Edit</span>
        </b-dropdown-item>
      </b-dropdown>
    </template>

  </b-table>
```

**Method to obtain the data:**

```
async getInventories() {
  this.isBusy = true
  try {
    const response = await storeService.getInventories()
    if (response.status === 200) {
      this.loading = false
      this.isBusy = false
      this.items = response.data.data
      this.moment(this.items.created_at)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    this.isBusy = false
    this.loading = false
    this.showToast('Warning', 'AlertCircleIcon', 'False', 'warning')
  }
},
```